# Proving that $\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\tanh^{-1}(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\beta(4)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}G$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, polylogarithm

I am trying to prove that
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\tanh^{-1}(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\beta(4)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}G$$
where $\beta(s)$ is the [Dirichlet Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) and $G$ is the [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). I managed to derive the following series involving polygamma functions but it doesn't seem to be of much help.

$$
\begin{align*}
I &=\frac{1}{64}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\psi_2 \left(\frac{n}{2}+1 \right) -\psi_2\left(\frac{n+1}{2} \right)}{2n+1}  \\
&= \frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\psi_2(n)}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{32}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi_2\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{2n-1}
\end{align*}
$$

Numerical calculations show that $I \approx 0.235593$.

Comment: I'm interested as to where this integral arrived. Where did you find it?

Comment: If only it was $\arctan(x)$ instead of $\text{arctanh}(x)$

Comment: $$I=\frac{3 \pi \zeta(3)}{64}+\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_3 (u^2)}{1+u^2} du$$

Comment: Wow, this is though (mathematica can't do that one)...nice question (+1)

Comment: likewise $$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^4(x)\tanh^{-1}(x)}{1+x^2}dx=12\beta(6)-{\pi^2}\beta(4)-\frac{\pi^4}{60}G$$

Comment: A simple substitution of the form $x\to\dfrac1x$ yields $I~=~\dfrac12~\Re\bigg[\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2x}{1+x^2}~\tanh^{-1}x~dx\bigg],~$ which can easily be rewritten as  $\dfrac12~\Re\Big[J''(0)\Big],~$ where $J(k)~=~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^k}{1+x^2}~\tanh^{-1}x~dx,~$ at which point we take into consideration the fact that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{1+x^n}~dx ~=~ \frac\pi n~\csc\bigg(k~\frac\pi n\bigg).$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem on my own.

Using integration by parts,
$$\begin{align*}
&\; \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\tanh^{-1}(x)}{1+x^2}dx \\
&= -2\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\tan^{-1}(x)\tanh^{-1}(x)}{x}dx-\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\tan^{-1}(x)}{1-x^2}dx \tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

I posted the solution to both these integrals on another forum. Here are the links:

1. http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic711.html#p3975
2. http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic245.html#p1680

$$\begin{align*}\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\tan^{-1}(x)\tanh^{-1}(x)}{x}dx &= \frac{\pi^2}{16}G-\frac{7\pi\zeta(3)}{32} \tag{2}\\
\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(x)\tan^{-1}(x)}{1-x^2}dx &= -\beta(4)-\frac{\pi^2}{24}G+\frac{7\pi}{16}\zeta(3)\tag{3}
\end{align*}$$
$G$ denotes the Catalan's constant and $\beta(4)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^4}$. Substituting these two results in equation (1) gives:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\tanh^{-1}(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\beta(4)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}G \tag{4}$$

**Proof sketch of integrals (2) and (3) : (Please see the above links for  a more detailed answer)**

The idea behind evaluating (2) and (3) is breaking them down into Euler Sums. Using the taylor series expansion $\tan^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ and integrating term-wise, we obtain the following relations:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\tan^{-1}(x)\tanh^{-1}(x)}{x}dx &= -\log(2)\frac{\pi^3}{32}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}\left( \gamma+\psi_0(n+1)\right) \\ &\;+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \psi_1(n+1)}{(2n+1)^2}  \tag{5}\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\tan^{-1}(x)}{1-x^2}dx &=-\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\psi_2(n+1)}{2n+1}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

These Euler Sums can be evaluated using the techniques shown in the paper "Euler Sums and Contour Integral Representations" by Philippe Flajolet and Bruno Salvy. Here is it's [link](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf). 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\psi_2(n+1)}{2n+1} &= 8\beta(4)+\frac{\pi^2}{3}G-\frac{7\pi}{2}\zeta(3) \\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\psi_1(n+1)}{(2n+1)^2} &= 6\beta(4)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}G-\frac{7\pi}{4}\zeta(3) \\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\left( \gamma+\psi_0(n+1)\right)}{(2n+1)^3} &= 3\beta(4)-\frac{7\pi}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^3}{16}\log(2)
\end{align*}
Substituting these into equations (5) and (6) gives us the integrals (2) and (3).

**A related integral**

Using similar techniques, we can show that
$$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\tan^{-1}(x)}{x\left(1-x^2 \right)}dx=\beta(4)+\frac{7\pi \zeta(3)}{64}+\frac{\pi^3 \log(2)}{32}$$

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

Here is a beautiful generalization of the integral calculated below.

> Let $n$ be a natural number. Then, we have 
>   $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^{2n-1}(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(2^{-2 n-1}-1\right) \zeta (2 n+1) (2n-1)!$$
>   $$+\frac{\pi}{16} \lim_{s\to0}\left(\frac{d^{2n-1}}{ds^{2n-1}}\left(\frac{1}{s}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}s\right)\left(\pi+\psi\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)\right)\right)\right),$$
>   where $\zeta$ represents the Riemann zeta function and $\psi$ denotes the Digamma function.

All details will appear soon in a new paper.

---

**A solution by Cornel I. Valean to one of the resulting integrals in Shobhit Bhatnagar's post**

> Let's show that
>   $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x=\frac{3}{8}\zeta(2)G-\frac{7}{32}\pi \zeta(3),$$
>   **without using harmonic series**.

We want to begin with the variable change $x \mapsto 1/x$ and use that $\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}, \ x>0$, and  $\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\operatorname{arctanh}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}i, \ x>1$. Then, we write

$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x=-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(1/x)\arctan(1/x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)(\pi/2i+\operatorname{arctanh}(x))(\pi/2-\arctan(x))}{x}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\Re\biggr \{\int_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}-\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\right)\textrm{d}x \biggr\}$$
$$=\Re\biggr \{\left(\int_0^{\infty}-\int_0^{1}\right)\left(\frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}-\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\right)\textrm{d}x \biggr\}$$
$$=\Re\biggr \{\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}-\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\right)\textrm{d}x \biggr\}$$
$$-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x}_{\displaystyle I}+\frac{\pi}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x}_{\displaystyle -7/8\zeta(3)},$$
whence we obtain that
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\Re\biggr \{\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}-\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\right)\textrm{d}x \biggr\}-\frac{7}{32}\pi \zeta(3)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\Re\biggr \{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x \biggr\}-\frac{\pi}{4}\Re\biggr \{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x \biggr\}$$
$$-\frac{7}{32}\pi \zeta(3),\tag1$$

where in the calculations I used the fact that $\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x=\int_0^1 \log(x) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{x^{2n-2}}{2n-1}\textrm{d}x$$ $$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n-1}\int_0^1 x^{2n-2}\log(x)\textrm{d}x=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}=-\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)$.

For the second integral in $(1)$ , we have 
$$\Re\biggr \{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x \biggr\}=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x+\Re\biggr \{\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x \biggr\}$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x+\Re\biggr \{\int_1^{\infty}\frac{(\operatorname{arctanh}(1/x)-\pi/2 i)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x \biggr\}$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x-\Re\biggr \{\int_0^1\frac{(\operatorname{arctanh}(x)-\pi/2 i)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x \biggr\}$$
$$=0.\tag2$$

Combining the results in $(1)$ and $(2)$, we arrive at 
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\Re\biggr \{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x \biggr\}-\frac{7}{32}\pi \zeta(3). \tag3$$

At this point, we consider the generalized integral result,

> $$\displaystyle J(s)=\Re \biggr\{\int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)\textrm{d}x\biggr\}$$ $$=\frac{\pi}{8s}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}s\right)\left(\pi+\psi\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)\right),$$ 
>    $0>s>-2$ (which can be extended to $1>s>-2$), we want to prove. 
>   **(Is this new in the mathematical literature?)**

Using integral representations of $\arctan(x)$ and $\operatorname{arctanh}(x)$, we write
$$J(s)=\Re \biggr\{\int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)\textrm{d}x\biggr\}$$
$$=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^1\left( PV\int_0^1\frac{x^{s+1}}{(1-y^2 x^2)(1+z^2 x^2)}\textrm{d}y\right) \textrm{d}z\right)\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\int_0^1\left( \int_0^1\left(PV\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s+1}}{(1-y^2 x^2)(1+z^2 x^2)}\textrm{d}x\right) \textrm{d}z\right)\textrm{d}y$$
$$=\int_0^1\left( \int_0^1\frac{y^2}{y^2+z^2}\left(PV\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s+1}}{1-y^2 x^2}\textrm{d}x\right) \textrm{d}z\right)\textrm{d}y$$
$$+\int_0^1\left( \int_0^1\frac{z^2}{y^2+z^2}\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s+1}}{1+z^2 x^2}\textrm{d}x\right) \textrm{d}z\right)\textrm{d}y$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\left( \int_0^1\frac{y^{-s}}{y^2+z^2}\left(PV\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s/2}}{1-x}\textrm{d}x\right) \textrm{d}y\right)\textrm{d}z$$
$$+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\left( \int_0^1\frac{z^{-s}}{y^2+z^2}\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s/2}}{1+x}\textrm{d}x\right) \textrm{d}y\right)\textrm{d}z$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)\int_0^1\left( \int_0^1\frac{y^{-s}}{y^2+z^2} \textrm{d}z\right)\textrm{d}y-\frac{\pi}{2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)\int_0^1\left( \int_0^1\frac{z^{-s}}{y^2+z^2} \textrm{d}y\right)\textrm{d}z$$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{2}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}s\right)\int_0^1\left( \int_0^1\frac{y^{-s}}{y^2+z^2} \textrm{d}z\right)\textrm{d}y=-\frac{\pi}{2}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}s\right)\int_0^1 y^{-1-s}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(y)\right)\textrm{d}y$$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{2}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}s\right)\left(-\frac{\pi}{4s}-\frac{1}{s}\int_0^1\frac{y^{-s}}{1+y^2}\textrm{d}y\right)$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{8s}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}s\right)\left(\pi+\psi\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)\right).$$

Now, based upon the previous result, it's easy to see that
$$\lim_{s\to0}\frac{d}{ds}\{\Re\{J(s)\}\}=\lim_{s\to0}\frac{d}{ds}\biggr\{\Re\biggr\{\int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)\textrm{d}x\biggr \}\biggr\}$$
$$=\lim_{s\to0}\frac{d}{ds}\biggr\{\frac{\pi}{8s}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}s\right)\left(\pi+\psi\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)\right)\biggr\}$$
$$=\frac{3}{64}\zeta(2)\left(\psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)$$
$$=\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)G,\tag4$$
which is immediately clear if we use the Trigamma series representation, $\displaystyle \psi^{(1)}(z)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+k)^2}$, and then recognize in the difference of the Trigamma special values the series representation of the Catalan's constant, $\displaystyle G=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}$.

Combining the results in $(3)$ and $(4)$, we conclude that

> $$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x=\frac{3}{8}\zeta(2)G-\frac{7}{32}\pi \zeta(3),$$
>   which is the desired result.

For example, using the same strategy we may get a generalization of the present integral. Another such exotic integral we may get is

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^3(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\arctan(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{3}{1024}\zeta(2)\psi^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{945}{256}\zeta(6)-\frac{93}{64}\pi\zeta(5)+\frac{45}{64}\zeta(4)G,$$
>   which looks really nice, isn't it?

**A first note**:  The other integral in **Shobhit Bhatnagar**'s post may be done in a similar style $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\tanh^{-1}(x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x,$ which can also be reduced to integrals already found in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, like

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\log^2(x)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x=\frac{21}{64}\pi \zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^3}{32}\log(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{24}G.$$

The other integral with $1-x$ in denominator may be calculated by a strategy similar to the one presented in this post.

**A second note**: Using the **Cauchy product**  $\displaystyle \arctan(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \sum _{n=1}^{2 k-1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^{4 k-2}}{(2 k-1) (2 n-1)}$, is another way of attacking the integrals. For example, using the results with integrals previously given, we get other beautiful results with series

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^3} \sum _{n=1}^{2 k-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2 n-1}=\frac{7 }{8}\pi  \zeta (3)-\frac{3 }{2}\zeta(2)G,$$

or

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^5}\sum _{n=1}^{2 k-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2 n-1}$$
>   $$=\frac{315}{32}\zeta (6)-\frac{15 }{8}\zeta(4)G+\frac{31 }{8}\pi  \zeta (5)-\frac{1}{128} \zeta (2) \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right).$$

Comment: Outstanding solution +1

Answer (score 3):

The generalization of the **main integral** follows easily by employing the same ideas used in this post and the previous one.

> Let $n$ be a natural number. Then, we have 
>   $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^{2n}(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\lim_{s\to0}\frac{d^{2n}}{ds^{2n}}\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\cot \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right) \left(\psi \left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{s}{4}\right)\right)-\frac{\pi ^2 }{16} \csc \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right)\right),$$
>   where $\psi$ represents the Digamma function.

**Another similar generalization**

> Let $n$ be a natural number. Then, we get 
>   $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^{2n}(x)\arctan(x)}{1-x^2}\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{\pi}{4} \left(1-2^{-2 n-1}\right) \zeta (2 n+1)(2 n)!$$
>   $$-\lim_{s\to0}\frac{d^{2n}}{ds^{2n}}\left(\frac{\pi}{16} \csc \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right) \left(\pi  \cos \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{s+1}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{s+3}{4}\right)\right)\right),$$
>   where $\zeta$ represents the Riemann zeta function and $\psi$ denotes the Digamma function.
>
> ---

**A solution in large steps by Cornel I. Valean  to the main integral**
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

We follow the strategy used to the auxiliary result from the previous post, and then we immediately arrive at

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\Re\biggr\{ \int_0^{\infty } \frac{\log ^2(x) \operatorname{arctanh}(x)}{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x\biggr \}$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty }\left(PV\int_0^1 \frac{x \log ^2(x)}{(1-y^2 x^2)(1+x^2)} \textrm{d}y\right)\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\left(PV\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x \log ^2(x)}{(1-y^2 x^2)(1+x^2)} \textrm{d}x\right)\textrm{d}y$$
>   $$=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\int_0^1 \frac{\log(y)}{1+y^2}\textrm{d}y-\frac{1}{6}\int_0^1 \frac{\log^3(y)}{1+y^2}\textrm{d}y=\beta(4)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}G,$$
>   as desired.

End of story.

**A note:** Using the **Cauchy product** $\displaystyle \frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)}{1+x^2}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{n+k} x^{2 n-1}}{2 k-1}$, an the value of the main integral, we immediately obtain the beautiful series

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3} \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2 k-1}=4\beta(4)-\frac{\pi^2}{3}G.$$

**Some kind of bonus:** Using the integrals relation obained with integration by parts as shown in **Shobhit Bhatnagar**'s post and combining it with the results obtained in this post and the previous one, we obtain the value of the other integral,

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(x)\arctan(x)}{1-x^2}\textrm{d}x= -\beta(4)-\frac{\pi^2}{24}G+\frac{7\pi}{16}\zeta(3).$$

**A note:** It's clear the generalization $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\log^{2n}(x)\arctan(x)}{1-x^2}\textrm{d}x$ may be approached in the same way as $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)}{1+x^2}dx$.