# Compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

How to evaluate $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx\ ?$$

where $\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_3(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^3}$ , $|x|\leq1$

I came across this integral while I was working on $\displaystyle \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx\ $ and here is how I established a relation between these two integrals:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx-\underbrace{\int_1^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx}_{x\mapsto 1/x}$$

$$=\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx-\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(1/x)}{1+x^2}\ dx$$
$$\left\{\color{red}{\text{add the integral to both sides}}\right\}$$

$$2\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1/x)}{1+x^2}\ dx$$

$$\{\color{red}{\text{use}\ \operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1/x)=2\zeta(2)\ln x-\frac16\ln^3x+i\frac{\pi}2\ln^2x}\}$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx+2\zeta(2)\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\ dx}_{-G}-\frac16\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x^2}\ dx}_{-6\beta(4)}+i\frac{\pi}2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1+x^2}\ dx}_{2\beta(3)}$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx-2\zeta(2)G+\beta(4)+i\pi \beta(3)$$

Then

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx-\zeta(2)G+\frac12\beta(4)+i\frac{\pi}2 \beta(3)\tag{1}$$

where $\displaystyle\beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}\ $ is the [the Dirichlet beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function?fbclid=IwAR2JKUjyn8sG4wMdUfeT3JyJLpw7C-aanbnwRYbIZ0k9QYwA3Hz1_0OsQhU).

So any idea how to evaluate any of these two integrals?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Note the formula you got from the triglogarithmic identity involved you being cavalier about branch cuts; you are missing a factor of $\frac{16 i \pi^4}{512}$

Comment: @clathratus I am not sure if you are being sarcastic or not but I'll take as not. If you want to know what I'm asking just ignore the body and read the title please.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen wolfram gives the closed form.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I dont think I'm missing any. To make sure, just take x=1/2 and compare the two sides.

Comment: You definitely are. The integral from $0$ to $1$ is entirely real, but the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ passes through imaginary values; [As Wolfram Alpha calculates](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+Li_3(x)+%2F+(x%5E2%2B1)+from+0+to+Infinity), you end up with an extra imaginary factor of $\frac{-16 i \pi^4}{512}$. I already checked this in Mathematica earlier. It comes from the fact the identities you cite are only usually valid on certain domains, e.g. $(0,1)$ or $(1,\infty)$. You tried to apply the result without taking into account that you have to choose branches carefully

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen oh I got what you mean now. In your previous comment I thought you meant the trilogarithmic identity i used is missing something. It was just misunderstanding. Yes we can simply ignore that imaginary term as we are interested in only real value.

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to clarify for anyone reading. Also note that in the closed form we get two PolyGamma values and a Zeta value. It is very quick to check that the Zeta value comes from the residue at $\pm i$ (choose whichever you wish) but I am not sure how the PolyGamma functions come in; likely the contour does not vanish as we would desire along nice arcs so these serve as a correction factor

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @AliShather I was not being sarcastic, I was just confused by the wording of the post. Thank you for explaining! (+1)

Comment: @clathratus its ok its edited now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Finally I got the answer**:

Using the generalized integral expression of the polylogrithmic function which can be found in the book ***(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums and series*** page 4.

$$\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^n(u)}{1-xu}\ du=(-1)^n n!\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}(x)$$ and by setting $n=2$ we get

$$\operatorname{Li}_{3}(x)=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2 u}{1-xu}\ du$$

we can write

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac12\int_0^1\ln^2u\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{(1-ux)(1+x^2)}\ dx\right)\ du$$
$$=\frac12\int_0^1\ln^2u\left(-\frac12\left(\frac{\pi u}{1+u^2}+\frac{2\ln(-u)}{1+u^2}\right)\right)\ du,\quad \color{red}{\ln(-u)=\ln u+i\pi}$$

$$=-\frac{\pi}{4}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{u\ln^2u}{1+u^2}\ du}_{\frac3{16}\zeta(3)}-\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{1+u^2}\ du}_{-6\beta(4)}-i\frac{\pi}2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2u}{1+u^2}\ du}_{2\beta(3)}$$

Then

> $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=-\frac{3\pi}{64}\zeta(3)+3\beta(4)-i\pi\beta(3)\tag{2}$$

---

**Bonus:**

By combining $(1)$ in the question body and $(2)$, the imaginary part $i\pi\beta(3)$ nicely cancels out and we get

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=2\beta(4)-\zeta(2)G-\frac{3\pi}{128}\zeta(3)$$

where [$\beta(4)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function?fbclid=IwAR2JKUjyn8sG4wMdUfeT3JyJLpw7C-aanbnwRYbIZ0k9QYwA3Hz1_0OsQhU) $=\frac{1}{768}\psi^{(3)}(1/4)-\frac{\pi^4}{96}$

Comment: The formula \begin{align}\Re\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx&=\frac12\int_0^1\ln^2u\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{(1-ux)(1+x^2)}\ dx\right)\ du\end{align} is weird. In the right side it's $\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1+x^2}\ dx$ not its real part. There is no indication for the values of x involved in the formula about polylogarithm in the beginning of your post. Anyway your closed-form matches numeric evaluation.

Comment: its edited now. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: The formula for polylogarithm in the beginning of your post is valid for $|x|<1$ only. If you take $x=2$ the denominator is $1-2u$ and $1-2u=0$ when $u=1/2\in [0;1]$

Comment: Yes .. actually i got the right formula yesterday and I'll fix the problem today.

Comment: When you consider the integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{(1-ux)(1+x^2)}\ dx$$ as a CauchyPrincipalValue you don't get the imagniary part. It arises from the $\epsilon$ contour around that singularity.

Comment: @Diger I fixed it :)

Comment: @FDP I think its all clear now.

Comment: \begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^n(u)}{1-xu}\ du=(-1)^n n!\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}(x)\end{align} is true for $|x|\leq 1$. If you take $x=2$ the denominator of $\dfrac{x\ln^n(u)}{1-xu}$ is not defined. $1-2u=0$ when $u=1/2$ included in the range of integration.

Comment: @FDP what about $Li_2(2)$ for example? here we have $2>1$ so does that mean we dont have a value for  $Li_2(2)$? we do but we will have an imaginary part and that is what happened in our case here. I think you, Zacky and me talked about this issue before if you remember.

Comment: @Ali Shater: it does mean the identity is not always true. You probably knows that $\displaystyle \zeta(0.5)\neq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{0.5}}$ but $\displaystyle \zeta(2)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ is true.

Comment: @FDP nice example but please check our conversation here its about this issue. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3261771/evaluate-int-limits-0-infty-frac-ln21x1x2-dx

Comment: @FDP: In the case of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/2}}$ the sum does not converge. But for $x>1$ the integral here does converge in a certain sense.

Comment: @Ali Shather: If you take $x$ to be a complex value not real, the denominator cannot be zero thus the integral converges.

Comment: @Diger: i'm curious to know what is this "certain sense".

Comment: The proof of $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{x\ln^n(u)}{1-xu}\ du=(-1)^n n!\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}(x)$ is easy IF $|xu|<1$ is true for all $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Comment: @FDP so any idea how to avoid this issue? and do you think solution is mathematically wrong? just curious how i got the right answer and the imaginary parts cancelled out?

Comment: @FDP: Consider the line $(0,1)$ as an actual contour i.e. $CPV + i\pi \cdot$ residue at u=1/x. This way the integral is analytic in $x$ with the only problem at $x=1$ where it has a logarithmic singularity.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the explication of Diger.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to say branch point instead of logarithmic singularity.

Answer (score 6):

For a different solution, use the first result from [A simple idea to calculate a class of polylogarithmic integrals by using the Cauchy product of squared Polylogarithm function by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337739055_A_simple_idea_to_calculate_a_class_of_polylogarithmic_integrals_by_using_the_Cauchy_product_of_squared_Polylogarithm_function).

Essentially, the main new results in the presentation are:

> Let $a\le1$ be a real number. The following equalities hold: 
>   \begin{equation*}
> i) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log (x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x) }{1-a x} \textrm{d}x=\frac{(\operatorname{Li}_2(a))^2}{2 a}+3\frac{\operatorname{Li}_4(a)}{a}-2\zeta(2)\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(a)}{a};
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> ii) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x) }{1-a x} \textrm{d}x=20\frac{\operatorname{Li}_6(a)}{a}-12 \zeta(2)\frac{\operatorname{Li}_4(a)}{ a}+\frac{(\operatorname{Li}_3(a))^2}{a}.
> \end{equation*}
>   *For a fast proof, see the paper above (series expansion combined with the Cauchy product of squared Polylogarithms*)

The use of these new results with integrals allows you to obtain your result elegantly, but also other results that are (very) difficult to obtain by other means, including results from the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**.

**BONUS:** Using these results you may also establish that (or the versions with integration by parts applied).

> $$i) \ \int_0^1  \frac{\arctan(x) \operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{384}\left(720\zeta(4)+105\pi\zeta(3)+384\zeta(2)G-\psi^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right),$$
>   $$ii)\ \int_0^1  \frac{\arctan(x) \operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{768}\left(\psi^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-384\zeta(2)G-126\pi\zeta(3)-720\zeta(4)\right).$$

---

**EXPLANATIONS** (OP's request): The following way in large steps shows the amazing possible creativity in such calculations.

We'll want to focus on the integral, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$ which is a *translated* form of the main integral.

Now, based on $i)$ where we plug in $a=i$ and then consider the real part, we obtain an integral which by a simple integration by parts reveals that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\log(1-x) \log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x+\frac{17}{48}\pi^2 G+\frac{\pi^4}{32}-\frac{1}{256}\psi^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right).$$

Looks like we need to evaluate one more integral and we're done. Well, if you read the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** (did you?), particularly the solutions in the sections **3.24** & **3.25** you probably observed the powerful trick of splitting the nonnegative real line at $x=1$ with the hope of getting the same integral in the other side but with an opposite sign. Therefore, with such a careful approach (since we need to avoid the divergence issues), we obtain immediately that 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\log(1-x) \log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)\log^2(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x}_{\text{Trivial}}+\frac{\pi}{4}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}\textrm{d}x}_{\text{Trivial}}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\Re\left \{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(1/x) \log(1-x)\log(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x\right \},$$

and the last integral works simply nice with **Cornel**'s strategy described in the second part of this post (it involves the use of Cauchy Principal Value) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3488566.

Comment: The explanation is really amazing and helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I assume we're using the principal branch of the trilogarithm, and we're integrating on the lower side of the branch cut (which is what Mathematica assumes).

Let's integrate the function $$f(z) = \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(z)}{1+z^{2}}, \quad s>0,$$

around a contour consisting of the real axis from $z= -R$ to $z=1-\epsilon$, a small clockwise-oriented semicircle of radius $\epsilon$ about the point $z=1$, the lower side of the branch cut from $z=1+\epsilon $ to $z= R$, and a counterclockwise-oriented semicircle in the **lower** half-plane of radius $R$.

As $ R \to \infty$, the integral vanishes on the semicircle since $\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(z)}{1+z^{2}} $ is asymptotic to $-\frac{\ln^{s}(-z)}{\Gamma(s+1)z^{2}} $ as $|z| \to \infty$. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Asymptotic_expansions).)

And the integral vanishes on the small semicircle as $\epsilon \to 0$ since $s>0$. (When $s = 0$, the singularity at $z=1$ becomes a simple pole.)

Therefore, we have $$ \begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(x)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(-x)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(x)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \color{red}{-} 2 \pi i \operatorname*{Res}_{z=-i} f(z)  \\ &= \pi  \operatorname{Li}_{s}(-i) \\ &\overset{\clubsuit}{=} -\pi \left(2^{-s} \eta(s)+i \beta(s) \right). \end{align}$$

In a [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4828978/16033) I used contour integration to show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(-x)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx = - s \beta(s+1) - \pi 2^{-s-1} \eta(s), \quad s >0.  $$

Using that result, we get $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{s}(x)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx = -\pi \, 2^{-s-1} \eta(s) + s \beta(s+1) - i \pi \beta(s). $$

For $s=3$ we have

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}(x)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx &= - \frac{\pi}{16} \eta(3) + 3 \beta(4) - i \pi \beta(3) \\ &= - \frac{\pi}{16} \left(1-2^{-2}  \right) \zeta(3) + 3 \beta(4) - i \pi \left(\frac{\pi^{3}}{32} \right) \\ &= - \frac{3 \pi}{64} \zeta(3) +3 \beta(4) - \frac{i \pi^{4}}{32}. \end{align}$$

---

$\clubsuit$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions

---

Wolfram Alpha seems to have a bit of difficulty approximating the value of the integral when $s$ is between $0$ and $1$. I think this has to do with the behavior of $\operatorname{Li}_{s}(z)$ near $z=1$ when $s <1$.

When $s>1$,  $\lim_{z \to 1} \operatorname{Li}_{s}(z)$ exists and is finite.  But when $s <1$, $\operatorname{Li}_{s}(z)$ behaves like $\Gamma(1-s)(- \ln z)^{s-1}$ near $z=1$. See the discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Series_representations).

Comment: Thank you Random (+1). I managed to find more generalized integrals in this preprint https://www.researchgate.net/publication/379225908_EVALUATING_FOUR_GENERALIZED_POLYLOGARITHMIC_INTEGRALS?fbclid=IwAR3cUJoxWpqusS6xTpdZLkAX15Bk1SrEuue3NpCBKvUpy-Jl09RiSm5zP3M_aem_AUb0LTPW6s8nntTTxL6zwIrfLUaWU5j7XN0t_RHuEazcwjLtdX4XPJvohEMouLwfPN-s1KAEPO2BMgNwULfIIH0K