# How to find $I=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2x}{1+x}\left(\frac{\ln x}{1-x}+\ln(1+x)\right)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2x}{1+x}\left(\frac{\ln x}{1-x}+\ln(1+x)\right)dx=-\frac{\pi^4}{512}+\frac{3\pi^2}{128}\ln^22+\frac{\pi}{8}G\ln2-\frac{21}{64}\zeta(3)\ln2$$
 This integral was proposed to me by a friend, but without the solution.
 I tried the integration by parts, but too complex.
 I tried to find a closed form but without result.   $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2x}{1±x}\ln{x}dx$$

Comment: Your first integral for $I$ is $−0.103$ but your second is $−0.0606$ or $−0.296$. Are you saying that the integrals are the same because they don't seem to be?

Comment: (+1) for the question. The integral of the type $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2x}{1+x}\ln{x}\textrm{d}x$ can be reduced to simpler integrals to calculate by employing a very similar strategy to the one presented in section $3.24$, the generalization part from pages $142$-$145$, from the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**. The integral version with minus sign in denominator can be calculated in a similar style by cleverly employing the PVC idea.

Comment: In short,with the strategy I suggested you want to reach the value of $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan^2(x)\log(x)}{x(1+x)}\textrm{d}x,$$ and then, by symmetry, to extract the value of the desired integral. Grouping strategically the resulting integrals makes everything easier to do, and from what I saw one doesn't need to calculate immediately every integral that arises in the way. That's all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Partial solution:**

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2(x)\ln(x)}{1-x^2}dx+\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2(x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx$$

$$\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{I}_1+\mathcal{I}_2$$

---

**Evaluation of** $\mathcal{I}_2$:

Let $x\mapsto\frac{1-x}{1+x}$

$$\mathcal{I}_2=\int_0^1\arctan^2(x)\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan(x)\right)^2\ \frac{\ln(2)-\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx$$

$$=\ln(2)\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan(x)\right)^2}{1+x}dx}_{x\mapsto (1-x)/(1+x)}-\int_0^1\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan(x)\right)^2\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx$$

if we expand the second integral we get a symmetry

$$2\mathcal{I}_2=\ln(2)\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2(x)}{1+x}dx}_{IBP}-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx+\frac{\pi}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx}_{IBP}$$

$$\small{2\mathcal{I}_2=\frac{\pi^2}{16}\ln^2(2)-2\ln(2)\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx-\frac{\pi^2}{32}\ln^2(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{16}\ln^2(2)-\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx}$$

$$\mathcal{I}_2=\frac{3\pi^2}{64}\ln^2(2)-\ln(2)\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx-\frac{\pi}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx\tag1$$

---

For the first integral, we use the equality

$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x^2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{1+x}\right)dx=\frac{3\pi^2}{64}\ln(2)-\frac{\pi}{8}G$$

which can be proved easily through $x\mapsto\frac{1-x}{1+x}.$

allowing us to write

$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx-\frac{3\pi^2}{64}\ln(2)+\frac{\pi}{8}G$$
where

$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx\overset{x=\tan(\theta)}{=}-2\int_0^{\pi/4} \theta\ln(\cos\theta)d\theta=\frac{21}{64}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}{16}\ln(2)-\frac{\pi}{4}G$$

where the last result  follows from using the Fourier series of $$\ln(\cos x)=-\ln(2)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty 
\frac{(-1)^n\cos(2nx)}{n}$$

then

$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{21}{64}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}{64}\ln(2)-\frac{\pi}{8}G\tag2$$

As for the second integral, it is already calculated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279299/compute-int-01-frac-ln21x1x2-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1) where some results of harmonic series were used:

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=4\Im\operatorname{Li}_3(1+i)-\frac{7\pi^3}{64}-\frac{3\pi}{16}\ln^22-2G\ln2$$

but I don't think its a good idea to use this closed form as it has an imaginary term, so we better leave the integral as is hoping it cancels out with one of the sub-integrals of $$\mathcal{I}_1=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2(x)\ln(x)}{1-x^2}dx.$$

---

so by plugging $(2)$ in $(1)$ we get

> $$\mathcal{I}_2=\frac{\pi^2}{32}\ln^2(2)-\frac{21}{64}\ln(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi}{8}\ln(2)G-\frac{\pi}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: Very nice. These sorts of integrals seem to be your thing (+1)

Comment: @clathratus thank you :) I like these integrals but my favorite ones are those that's related to harmonic series. Any idea how to approach $\mathcal{I}_1$? It seems tough.

Comment: Perhaps using $$\arctan(x)^2=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n x^{2n+2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2n-2k+1)}?$$ Other than that I would have no Idea...

Comment: Good idea .. by the way the Taylor series of $\arctan^2(x)$ has s neat form.

Comment: Oh right. I couldn't think of it so I just used the Cauchy product

Comment: We know that $$\text{arctanh}^2(x)=-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n-2H_{2n}}{n}x^{2n}$$

replace $x$ by $ix$ and use the fact that $\text{arctanh}(ix)=i\arctan(x)$ we get 
$$\arctan^2(x)=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n-2H_{2n}}{n}x^{2n}$$

Comment: Very nice demonstration, congratulation (+1)

Comment: @user178256 thank you. Very nice question by the way. I'm still working on a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing on @AliShather's argument, let's focus on the integral 
\begin{align*}
I_1&=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2 x\ln x}{1-x^2}dx\\
&\overset{\rm IBP}=-\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2 x\mathop{\rm artanh} x}{x}+2\underbrace{\frac{\arctan x\mathop{\rm artanh} x \ln x}{1+x^2}}_{x\mapsto \frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2 x\mathop{\rm artanh} x}{x}-2{\frac{\left(\arctan x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\mathop{\rm artanh} x \ln x}{1+x^2}}dx\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\arctan^2 x\mathop{\rm artanh} x}{x}dx-\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\mathop{\rm artanh} x\ln x}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=-A-\frac{\pi}{4}B
\end{align*}
where $\mathop{\rm artanh}x=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$.

By converting into multiple integrals then integrating back, 
\begin{align*}
A&=\int_{[0,1]^4}\frac{x^2}{\left(1-s^2x^2\right)\left(1+t^2x^2\right)\left(1+u^2x^2\right)}dV\\[3px]
&=\mbox{*Partial fractions*}\\[3px]
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\mathop{\rm artanh}x}{x}\left(2\arctan x-\arctan\frac{1}{x}\right)\arctan\frac{1}{x}\,dx\\
&=-\frac{\pi^4}{64}+\pi\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x \mathop{\rm artanh}x}{x}dx}_{J}
\end{align*}
where we used the identity $\arctan x+\arctan\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

By $x\mapsto\frac{1-x}{1+x}$, 
$$J=\int_0^1\frac{\left(\arctan x-\frac\pi 4\right)\ln x}{1-x^2}dx=\frac{\pi^3}{32}+\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln x}{1-x^2}dx$$
Then by using IBP directly to J,
\begin{align*}
J&=-\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln x}{1-x^2}+\frac{\mathop{\rm artanh}x \ln x}{1+x^2}dx\\&=\frac{\pi^3}{64}-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\mathop{\rm artanh}x \ln x}{1+x^2}dx}_B 
\end{align*}

By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2972249), 
$$I_1=\frac\pi 4 B=\frac{3\pi^4}{256}-\frac{G\pi\ln 2}{4}-\frac \pi 2\mathfrak{I}\mathop{\rm Li_3}\frac{1+i}{2}+\frac{\pi^2\ln^2 2}{64}$$

Finally using the closed form of $I_2$ by @AliShather and $I=I_1+I_2$ we should get the desired identity, where of course the closed form of B was not necessary and can be replaced by the partial steps used in the evaluation of B.

Comment: Very nice, congratulation (+1)

Comment: Nice work  (+1). I like the multiple integral idea.