# Derive $Im \text{ Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)= \frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

I would like to have a derivation of the following close-form

$$Im \ \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)= \frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

I expect that I could just rely on the recursive representations of the polylogarithmic functions below

$$\text{Li}_3 \left(\frac{1+i}2\right)= \int_0^{\frac{1+i}2} \frac{\text{Li}_2(t)}t\ dt 
=  -\int_0^{\frac{1+i}2} \frac{dt}t\ \int_0^t\frac{\ln(1-s)}s ds
$$

and manipulate the RHS, (e.g. IBP, substitution, etc.) to arrive at the desired integral, with no luck yet. Would like to get some pointers in deriving it.

Comment: Your question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279299/compute-int-01-frac-ln21x1x2-dx/3449505#3449505) see Ali Shather's $2$nd answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useful formula
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 \frac{a (\ln(x))^2}{1-ax} dx = 2 \operatorname{Li}_3(a).
\end{eqnarray*}
Sub $x=1-u$ and partial fractions ... should give the result?

Also see FDP's answer here for something similar [Evaluate $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}\ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3261771/evaluate-int-limits-0-infty-frac-ln21x1x2-dx)